# Python: Create new dataframe column that shows a ranking relative to other column values

Tags: python, pandas

Original dataframe in python:

```
    date       cash  hy    equity  
0  2003-01-31   1    3       4                    
1  2003-01-31   2    5       1                     
2  2003-01-31   1    6       3
```

Goal: Create three new columns that rank each asset class relative to the other two. 0 = lowest return asset class. 2 = highest returning asset class.

```
    date       cash  hy    equity  cash_rank    hy_rank    equity_rank
0  2003-01-31   1    3       4          0        1            2
1  2003-01-31   2    5       1          1        2            0
2  2003-01-31   1    6       3          0        2            1
```

I was using the code below:

```
x = [2, 5, 1]
arranged = sorted(x)

sorted_list =  []

for i in x:
    sorted_list.append(arranged.index(i))
```

This returns the new sorted_list = [1, 2, 0] which is the order of the asset class returns in the second row.

I can't figure out how to apply this to the rank columns with the dataframe.apply() method or any other method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `apply` `rank`

```
df = df.join(df.loc[:,'cash':].apply(pd.Series.rank,1).sub(1).add_suffix('_rank'))
df
Out[145]: 
         date  cash  hy  equity  cash_rank  hy_rank  equity_rank
0  2003-01-31     1   3       4        0.0      1.0          2.0
1  2003-01-31     2   5       1        1.0      2.0          0.0
2  2003-01-31     1   6       3        0.0      2.0          1.0
```

Comment: That was fast! Nice answer :) +1